# Computer is slow after entering wrong pin in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I realize this sounds strange, but I have noticed this behaviour on my computer:

If I enter a wrong pin, and then afterwards the correct pin when logging into Windows, my computer is slow for the rest of the session. I have to restart the computer for it work properly again.

Could there be CPU throttling or something similar happening?

Comment: This sounds very strange - have you tried to repeat this multiple times? with no wrong attempts, 1 wrong attempts and more than 1 wrong attempt before entering correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by "slow"?